# Why is a webserver responding with code 400 (BAD REQUEST) AFTER it has sent a code 200 (OK)

Tags: c#, http, .net-core, tcp

For a project I am trying to setup a TCP connection between a client and a webserver. When I do a get request to the root of the webserver I first get a 200(OK) response but after that the webserver sends a 400(Bad request) response. Note that I do not send any extra requests so this is the second response on my first request. The webserver I have running is a simple node.js server that returns "Hello World".

**Request to the webserver**

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8001
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
```

**Response from the webserver**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Tue, 18 Aug 2020 09:13:06 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

c
Hello world

0

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Connection: close
```

**Code for the webserver**

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200,  {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    response.end('Hello world\n')
}).listen(8081);

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/');
```

**Wireshark printout of the connection**
[image: Wireshark printout of the tcp connection]

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with C# or .NET Core? The web server looks like it's Express?

Comment: This is illegal. A server gets a request and sends an answer. You can not expect any library or framework to handle this as it is simply a very bad and illegal return. Any framewok will just stop after the OK and be done. ANyhow, wat is your question? YOu describe an issue, you totally fail to ask a single querstion.

Comment: You may have some sort of routing loop.  You are getting duplicates which means the ACK messages are not getting back to the source.  Look at the sequence numbers for duplicates.  I would try from cmd.exe >Ping IP at both ends of connection.  Ping the client from the server and ping the server from the client.  I think you may have a route in one direction but not in the opposite or a routing loop.  Routing loops can be seen in wireshark by looking at the TTL number (time to live) and see if you always get same number hops.

Comment: You may have two machines with same IP.  Remove ethernet cable and ping from other end.  If you get a response then another machine has same IP.

Comment: @TomTom I did ask a question... the title of my question is the question

Comment: @jdweng everything is running on my localhost...

Comment: Then the answer is taht the server is broken and not following HTTP Standards. Simple likle that. Unless it is somehow getting magically a second request.

Comment: You cannot use loopback (127.0.0.1) for both source and destination IP.  It looks like the localhost on your machine is set to the loopback.  Normally the two ends of a connection use different IP address.  For IP you can use 1) IPAddress.Any 2) Loopback 127.0.0.1 3) Or IP address of machine.  So normally the server listens to IPAddress.Any and client connects to machine IP.  See : https://andrewlock.net/5-ways-to-set-the-urls-for-an-aspnetcore-app/

Comment: @jdweng I did a test with a client and a server on my local machine, both on loopback and it worked... you just need to assign them a different port number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem and it's so simple that it took me two days to find it. My buffer that I use to send to the webserver over the tcp connection was 4096 bytes long but my message was a lot shorter. The emtpy bytes were sent over a separate request and resulted in the 400 Bad Request response. I now trim my buffers to eliminate all the empty space in them before I send any requests. Thanks to all that helpes me!!